# thread priority or process priority?

Tags: linux

In linux, When we talk about prioirity, then whether it is thread priority or process priority? I am confused on this. nice() is used to define priority. In that case it defines priority for process or thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first line of `man 2 nice` gives us:

> nice - change process priority

Comment: While what you say is true, nice does not change the priority. It changes the niceness. There is a difference. Nicenesses indirectly affects the dynamic priority of threads on the default scheduler. Even with out changing the niceness, a task will loss dynamic priority by using a lot of cpu, and gain it by using less. This is why Unix machines do not lock up when a single thread (or n threads where n is number of cores) uses a lot of cpu.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux you can still change the process priority of a thread...
It's useful with the [CFQ scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFQ).

For example:

```
setpriority (PRIO_PROCESS, gettid(), 19);
```

(See https://gist.github.com/4093954).